# Adding days to @Today

Tags: lotus-notes

Might be a silly question but I'm trying to add (for example) 2 days to todays date via using @Today. Is there any way how to do that without using @Adjust in Formula Language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do so in Formula Language other than using @Adjust. I wonder what the reason would be to avoid @Adjust?

In LotusScript there is a function [CDat](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_CDAT_FUNCTION.html) that converts a number to a date/time value. I imagine the CDbl function would convert a date/time to a number. Assuming that is true, you could convert Today's date to a number (of days since Jan 1 1900) and then add 2 to it, and then convert it back to a date.

Comment: there is no need to convert anything. If you assign a field value to a variant of type date/time, then you can simply add 2 to it without any conversion and it will be 2 days in future...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context. Not sure why you wish to avoid `@Adjust`, but you will need to use it in some cases.

Are you trying to do it in a field on a form, for example to calculate a due date?

Let's say you have a "Computed When Composed" field called Due_DT.

You can do it with LotusScript. For example, you could force it with `PostOpen()` code via `Call Source.FieldSetText( "Due_DT", Cstr( Today() + 2 ) )`.

Generally though it's easier to use `@Adjust( @Today; 0; 0; 2; 0; 0; 0 )` to auto-populate the field with a value two days into the future.

On the other hand, if you are trying to manipulate the date as part of a LotusScript function or subroutine, then you can use Torsten's approach, or you can use the `NotesDateTime` class and its `AdjustDay()` method.

If you are trying to do it in a view, rethink the problem. Including `@Now` or `@Today` in view selection or column formulae impacts server performance. (The view indices are constantly refreshing.)